# Challenging integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have just seen a question regarding an integration, which is quite hard. Though, I guess the word “hard” here means it is not an integration that needs a specific complicated technique, but I do not know nor see the trick to simplify the integrand.

Find the definite integral

$$\int_0^1 (x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)\ldots (2566x+1)\left(\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{2x+1} + \ldots + \frac{2566}{2566x+1}\right) \,\Bbb dx$$

Comment: It is probably easier to just consider the first few terms

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1} (x + 1)(2x + 1)(3x + 1) \left( \frac{1}{x + 1} + \frac{2}{2x + 1} + \frac{3}{3x + 1} \right) dx \\
= &\int_{0}^{1} 1(2x + 1)(3x + 1) + 2(x + 1)(3x + 1) + 3(x + 1)(2x + 1) dx \\
= &\int_{0}^{1} (x + 1)'(2x + 1)(3x + 1) + (x + 1)(2x + 1)'(3x + 1) + (x + 1)(2x + 1)(3x + 1)' dx \\
= &\int_{0}^{1} [(x + 1)(2x + 1)(3x + 1)]' dx \\
= &\dots
\end{align}

Comment: Indeed, if you set $f(x)=(x+1)(2x+1)\dots(nx+1)$, then your integrand is just $f'(x)$. So the integral should be $f(1)-f(0)=(n+1)!-1$.

Answer (score 10):

Note that the sum inside the parentheses corresponds precisely to the derivative of the factor in front of it, so that the integral evaluates to
$$
\left.\prod_{k=1}^{2566} (1+kx)\right|_0^1 = \prod_{k=1}^{2566} (k+1) - 1 = \prod_{k=2}^{2567} k - 1 = 2567! - 1 \approx 1.845 \cdot 10^{7639}
$$

Comment: You mean that the entire integrand is the derivative of the factor in front of the parentheses, right? Can you elaborate a bit more on why that's the case?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can see it by factorizing the product rule as below, with three factors for instance : $$(fgh)' = f'gh + fg'h + fgh' = fgh\left(\frac{f'}{f} + \frac{g'}{g} + \frac{g'}{g}\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

If you define
$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^n (i\,x+1)=x^n \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)_n=\frac{x^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i{i\,x +1}=\frac{n x-\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)+\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}$$

even by induction, you can prove that

$$I_n=\int_0^1 P_n\,S_n=(n+1)!- 1$$

Answer (score 1):

We can start by opening up the brackets (the thinking behind that is that we know there is no simple product rule in integration and that the second bracket is not derivative of the first (or vice versa) so we cannot use substitution) to get :

$\frac {1*(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1)}{x+1} + \frac {2*(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1)}{2x+1} + \frac {3*(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1)}{3x+1} + \frac {4*(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1)}{4x+1} + .. + \frac {2556*(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1)}{2556x+1}$

Let us define $A_i(x) = ix+1,  Y = (x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)(4x+1)..(2556x+1) = \prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x)$

We did not cancel common factors because you can notice how the coefficient of x of the divding term is conveniently placed outside the multiplication in the numerator. So we can represent it as the derivative of the missing bracket (like $(x+1)' = 1, (2x+1)' = 2, (3x+1)' = 3$ ..). Again the thought process for this is just seeing that it would be too difficult to simplify this in terms of a polynomial by multiplying all brackets and so rather convert it into some form of (polynomial)*(polynomial derivative).

Thus we get finally get this : $(\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x))(\sum_{i=1}^{2556}\frac {A_i'(x)}{A_i(x)})$

Now you may know the product rule for differentitaion which states that $(F(x)G(x))' = F'(x)G(x) + G'(x)F'(x)$.
To extend this for n fucntions (let $<a_i(x)>$) you can take the ln of the whole function (let $y = ) \prod_{i=1}^na_i(x)$ and then differentiate on both sides by using the property that ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b) and $(ln(y))' = \frac {y'}{y}$.

$\therefore$ on the LHS we have $(ln(y))' = \frac {y'}{y}$ and on the RHS we have $(\sum_{i=1}^n ln(a_i(x)))'$. Using the distributive property of differentiation on addition to get $(\sum_{i=1}^n ln(a_i(x)))' = \sum_{i=1}^n (ln(a_i(x)))' = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i'(x)}{a_i(x)}$. Thus, $\frac {y'}{y} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i'(x)}{a_i(x)}$. Multiplying both sides by y and writing y =  $\prod_{i=1}^na_i(x)$, we get $y' = y * \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i'(x)}{a_i(x)} = (\prod_{i=1}^na_i(x)) * (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i'(x)}{a_i(x)}$).

This representation is coincidentally the exact same form as we are getting after opening the brackets inside the integral.

So coming back to that, we understand that $(\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x))(\sum_{i=1}^{2556}\frac {A_i'(x)}{A_i(x)}) = (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x))' = Y'$

So $\int_0^1 (x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)\ldots (2566x+1)\left(\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{2x+1} + \ldots + \frac{2566}{2566x+1}\right) \,\Bbb dx$

= $\int_0^1 (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x))(\sum_{i=1}^{2556}\frac {A_i'(x)}{A_i(x)}) dx$

= $\int_0^1 Y' dx$

$f'(x) = \frac {d(f(x))}{dx} \implies \int f'(x)dx = \int \frac {d(f(x))}{dx}dx = \int d(f(x)) = f(x)$

So $\int_0^1 Y' dx = Y = (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(x))|_0^1 = (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(1)) - (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(0))$

$A_i(0) = i(0) + 1 = 1, A_i(1) = i(1) + 1 = i + 1$

So finally we get $\int_0^1 (x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1)\ldots (2566x+1)\left(\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{2x+1} + \ldots + \frac{2566}{2566x+1}\right) \,\Bbb dx = (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(1)) - (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}A_i(0)) = (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}(i+1)) - (\prod_{i=1}^{2556}1) = 2557!-1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, when using MathJax, write the whole expression in math mode. For example, instead of writing `$\int d(f(x))$ = f(x)` write `$\int d(f(x)) = f(x)$`

Comment: I have tried implementing what you said. Kindly edit my answer if you think there is still some problem in it.